# Add Array Item into console.log

Tags: arrays, undefined, console.log, splice

Hi guys, I am trying to develop on a lesson regarding basic To Do lists. If, after deleting a ToDo item I wanted the console to print "Deleted *To Do Item*" how would I do that? This is what I have thus far for the delete portion of the To Do.

```
function deleteToDo() {
    var index = prompt("Enter index of todo to delete");
        todos.splice(index, 1);
        console.log("Deleted " + todos[index]);
}
```

The error I receive is that "todos[index] is undefined" which I kind of guess would happen, at this point I'm just winging various options and seeing what happens. Do I need to define something before the splice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the value before deleting:

```
function deleteToDo() {
   var index = prompt("Enter index of todo to delete");

   if (index >= 0 && index < todos.length) {
       var deletedItem = todos[index];
       todos.splice(index, 1);
       console.log(deletedItem);
   }
}
```